# Docker with mysql: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory

Tags: mysql, macos, docker

I am on Mac `10.11.3 (15D21)`

About Docker I have:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

For Mysql

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql                       latest              7a5866c2edbf        12 days ago         361.3 MB
...
```

I did the following:

- `mkdir -p /Users/me/docker/mysql/data`
- `chmod -R 777 /Users/me/docker/mysql/data`

(Even with sudo for each command)

It from `Pro Docker` and from: [Permission denied when mounting Docker volume in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445923/3665178)

Even doing:

- `docker -v /Users/me/docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql mysql chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`

It from: [Database Fails to Start - Host Directory as a Data Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626283)

When I execute: (showing in multiple lines for better visualisation)

```
docker run -v /Users/me/docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql --name manolitomysql
           -e MYSQL_DATABASE='mysqldb' -e MYSQL_USER='mysql' -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='mysql'
           -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD='yes' -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='' -d mysql
```

I always get:

```
$ docker logs manolitomysql
Initializing database
2016-03-27T16:04:33.520170Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-03-27T16:04:35.089907Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2016-03-27T16:04:35.090006Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2016-03-27 16:04:35 0x7f061a050740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139664183068480 in file fil0fil.cc line 868
InnoDB: Failing assertion: success
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:04:35 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68188 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xe57c7c]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x459)[0x7896b9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8d0)[0x7f0619c2d8d0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f061841b067]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f061841c448]
mysqld[0x75fc29]
mysqld[0x1180f68]
mysqld(_Z40fil_open_log_and_system_tablespace_filesv+0xe4)[0x1185a74]
mysqld[0x107afe0]
mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x3692)[0x107eb12]
mysqld[0xf4a05d]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7d3981]
mysqld[0xc53716]
mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x5c8)[0xc5a5c8]
mysqld[0x782164]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x7b2)[0x7835d2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f0618407b45]
mysqld[0x77a274]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

What extra configuration is need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the audience, the following works:

1 Create a Dockerfile with

```
FROM mysql:latest
RUN deluser mysql
RUN useradd mysql
RUN mkdir -p /Users/me/docker/mysql/data
RUN chmod -R 777 /Users/me/docker/mysql/data
```

2 Create a new image using the previous Dockerfile

3 Run your new container using the previous *new* image

Answer (score 1):

You may have better control using a Dockerfile with the following instructions:

```
RUN useradd mysql
RUN mkdir /var/lib/mysql && chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```